# Eclipse C++ Formatting

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am having trouble configuring Eclipse 4.2 to format my C++ initialization lists the way I would like.

What I am after is this:

```
class Foo
{
    int a;
    double b;
    char c;
private:
    Foo()
    : a(0), b(-1.0)
    , c('@')
    {}
};
```

There doesn't seem to be many configuration options to cause the colon to appear on the next line, unindented, and to have the initialization list flow onto the next line with a preceding comma.

Instead, this is what I end up with:

```
class Foo
{
    int a;
    double b;
    char c;
private:
    Foo() :
        a(0), b(-1.0),
        c('@')
    {
    }
};
```

Are there any configuration options that will give me what I am after?

Comment: At least I don't have an answer, I'm doing this manually. But I want to encourage you to keep that style, it's the easiest to maintain IMHO, when adding new members.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option. Eclipse CDT is an open-source project and they will probably welcome a patch that adds this feature.

You can read more about how to do this on the official [Eclipse CDT website](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/developers.php).